# Continuously update watchpoint while traversing linked list gdb

Tags: c, gdb

Lets say I have the following simplified code to loop through a linked list. Each node has a data pointer and next pointer.

```
1 while (pNode->next != NULL)
2 {
3    pNode->data = newData;
4
5    pNode = pNode->next;
6 }
```

How would I go about automatically setting up a watchpoint on the address of the current `pNode->data` and update it every time pNode changes? So have something like on line 1 delete the watchpoint and set a new watchpoint on `pNode->data`. And then since this doesn't happen always I would need to clear all watchpoints after so I don't halt unnecessarily so on line 7 clear all watchpoints.

This code is running in a multithreaded application and pNode list is shared so I am trying to find out who is changing my pNode->data between lines 3 and 5. I do have a latch that should be preventing changing the list while I iterate but because of this error we must be changing it somewhere without the latch and I want to find out where.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find out who is changing my pNode->data between lines 3 and 5.

What makes you think that `data` is getting modified between lines 3 and 5?
If the list is shared, `pNode->data` could be modified 5 iterations later, or when the loop is already done.

In general, debugging multithreaded programs with debugger is hard. You really need to prove that the program is correct *by construction*, that is: you need to confirm that every time `pNode->data` is modified, some mutex is held (I assume that's what you meant by "latch").

That said, you can achieve what you asked for.

Find the address of instruction *immediately* after line 3 ends, and set a breakpoint on that instruction (use `b *0xaddress` to do so). Attach commands to that breakpoint:

```
commands 1
silent
watch -l pNode->data
cont
end
```

Likewise, find the instruction just before `pNode` is assigned on line 5 and set a breakpoint there. Attach commands:

```
commands 2
silent
delete $bpnum
cont
end
```

This uses `$bpnum` convenience variable, which is set to the number of breakpoint that was last set.